# making a highscore list for a game i made in python

Tags: python

I am quite new at python.

So I am currently working on a highscore list for a game that I made using tkinter and python. So far I have the code:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import pickle

playerName = input("what is your name? ")
playerScore = int(input('Give me a score? '))

highscores = [
    ('Luke', 0),
    ('Dalip', 0),
    ('Andrew', 0),
]

highscores.append((playerName, playerScore))
highscores = sorted(highscores, key = itemgetter(1), reverse = True)[:10]

with open('highscore.txt', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(highscores, f)

highscores = []

with open('highscore.txt', 'rb') as f:
    highscores = pickle.load(f)
```

The problem is, it puts this into the file:

€]q (X   lukeqK†qX   LukeqK †qX   DalipqK †qX   AndrewqK †qe.
(and yes this is exactly what it looks like)

I don't know what is wrong with it can anyone help, please?

Comment: Why is this a problem? By using `pickle` you're serializing and unserializing your data into a binary format. You're trying to read the file contents of a file that doesn't contain unicode, that's why it looks weird. Does `highscores` after loading contain the correct information? If so, nothing's wrong.

Comment: There is nothing wrong here: `pickle` produces a binary representation of your data - so it's not supposed to be human readable. When you `load` your pickled file, you get your data back. If you want a human readable file, you could use `json`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#comparison-with-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pickle` produces a binary representation of your data - so it's not supposed to be human readable.

When you load your pickled file, you get your data back, so everything works fine.

If you want a human readable file, a common solution is to use json. See http://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#comparison-with-json for a comparison. In particular:

> JSON, by default, can only represent a subset of the Python built-in
>   types, and no custom classes; pickle can represent an extremely large
>   number of Python types (many of them automatically, by clever usage of
>   Python’s introspection facilities; complex cases can be tackled by
>   implementing specific object APIs).

You just have to use `json` instead of `pickle` in your code:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import json

try:
    with open('highscore.txt', 'r') as f:
        highscores = json.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    # If the file doesn't exist, use your default values
    highscores = [
        ('Luke', 0),
        ('Dalip', 0),
        ('Andrew', 0),
        ]

playerName = input("what is your name? ")
playerScore = int(input('Give me a score? '))

highscores.append((playerName, playerScore))
highscores = sorted(highscores, key = itemgetter(1), reverse = True)[:10]

with open('highscore.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(highscores, f)

highscores = []
```

The content of `highscore.txt` will look like:

```
[["thierry", 100], ["Luke", 0], ["Dalip", 0], ["Andrew", 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks Thierry it's worked! How do I get it so that once it's added the name to the file it stays there? Because when I re-run the code it gets rid of the score before.

Comment: You should read the highscores file before entering the new scores. I updated my answer.